# Bug appearance with Sound Manager 2 when container is hidden (tabs)

Tags: tabs, soundmanager2

I succeed to install Sound Manager 2 with multiples MP3s using like a playlist. This playlist is include in a tab (not talking about browser tab, just tabs in the same page) and I've got a bug with appearance. I use also the 360-ui player of SM2.
This is the scenario:

1. I display the tab containing the playlist (hidden by default)
2. I launch the first sound
3. I display an another tab
4. The first sound finish, so the second sound is play automatically
5. I display the tab containing the playlist and appareance of the player is not good.

Please can someone help me ?